# Using Google Drive Realtime API in context of a service account

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I've been playing around with the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet) with a view to building a small ASP.NET app which allows online collaboration on simple documents.

I have built a test app which uses a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to upload and access files in Drive for my Google Apps account. I wanted to use a service account because the idea I'm working with will not be viable if collaborators have to authenticate with Google accounts.

The next step is investigating the [Google Drive Realtime API](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328221053/https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart). The tutorial at that link uses a web application client ID and requires that you authenticate your Google account before you can edit the example text file.

Do you know if it's possible to use a service account here so that changes are made in an anonymous context? If so, can you point me at an example because my Google searches aren't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The realtime API does not allow anonymous access.  All users must have a Google account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is that a fact? If so do you know if this is likely to be something that will one day be introduced? I'd have thought that if a service account can be used to anonymously upload and read Drive documents, then it'd be reasonable to allow collaboration via the same authentication mechanism.

Comment: The realtime API is designed to be used from within the browser using client side javascript.  It probably possible to use a service account with delegation to make changes using the import/export functionality (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime), but you aren't going to get much collaboration that way.